# SpringBoot - Application is failed to run, since config file references variable thats configued in azure vault

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

In my springboot application I have my azure vault related configuration in my application-< env >.yml file, and I reference azure vault variables in my config class. The gradle build file has azure-vault-secret starter and related dependencies. my env properties are loaded in cloud config server and my application refers from there. When I deploy my application, application fails to initialize as the variables (those are configured in azure vault)  referenced in  Config class are not resolved. The same setup is working if I move azure vault connection configuration directly to application.yml.

I feel, to resolve the issue -  the azure connection to be established first before config class is initialized. Can somebody help on how to do that.

Comment: Would you be able to share some code with us please ?

Comment: @user2985038 you may have to refer this link -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-spring-boot#connect-to-key-vault to load config class as part of application boot up